# What were the effective ways to test my firewall

Tags: firewall, fortigate

Myself testing my internal firewall from external network,What were the effective ways of testing my firewall and ensuring that it secure

The methods which i tried were launching a stealth scan with sending ack packets to the firewall and checked whether my firewall filtering all my ports,

using nmap i tested using following commands :

```
nmap -v -sA -n mydomain -OA firewallaudit
```

other than that i tried to repeatedly ping the firewall and tested whether it rejects and blocks the floods of attacks

Its an internal firewall and myself testing for internal and external attacks,

the above said were the normal tests which i carried out to test my internal firewall,other than above anyother options to ensure that firewall is safe?how can i test my firewall that its efficiently configured or not?

Comment: Your question is confusing since you say you tested an internal firewall from an external network, and, later, you say you tested your internal firewall. Is it a firewall internal to your company, or is it a firewall on the WAN access to block external threats to you company?

Comment: Since you say it is an internal company firewall, please edit the question to detail what sorts of internal threats you intend it to block.

Comment: It depends on what you want to block. For instance, our internal firewalls for labs are set to block routing protocols and other certain things, depending on the lab type. For LANs that vendors have access to, we want to block the vendors from the production network, but not necessarily the data traffic. What specifically are you trying to achieve with the firewall. The answer of efficient configuration depends on what you want it to do.

Comment: @RonMaupin myself noob in this area,any external resources or reference regarding general things which i need to test ,or like general firewall checklist?

Comment: Again, it depends on what you want the firewall to protect you from. Since you are looking to protect from one place inside your network to another place inside your network, you should have a clear idea of what is is you want to block/allow.

Comment: A small diagram may be useful, too.

Comment: I'll second @RonMaupin 's comment that you need to understand what exactly you are protecting, and from what kinds of threats.  At a minimum, you should know what ports you want open or blocked.